# Where is IRepository Defined - ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

I'm trying to figure out where IRepository interface lies and is defined:

public IRepository Repository { get; set; }

in this code here:
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/src/RedisStackOverflow/RedisStackOverflow.ServiceInterface/AnswersService.cs

so is this IRepository part of the ServiceStack framework and ServiceStack's built-in IoC is injecting using this?  I just want to know where to go find more about where this code is originating from.

I looked at the Redis ServiceModel but so is this Repository interface from the ServiceStack framework somewhere?  I'm trying to understand more of the ORM part of Service stack and not sure if that's where this is coming from or what...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That interface is just part of the [redis example project](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/tree/master/src/RedisStackOverflow). The source can be found [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/src/RedisStackOverflow/RedisStackOverflow.ServiceInterface/IRepository.cs). When trying to hunt down something like this look at the namespaces that are imported:

```
using RedisStackOverflow.ServiceModel;
using ServiceStack.ServiceInterface;
```

We know that if we are referencing `IRepository` in the code it must either be in the curernt namespace or one of those two.

Comment: Right, which like all ServiceStack dependencies are defined in `AppHost.Configure()`, which for [this example is here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/src/RedisStackOverflow/RedisStackOverflow/Global.asax.cs#L33).

Comment: @CoffeeAddict There is one though. It is in the [RedisStackOverflow](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/tree/master/src/RedisStackOverflow) project under the [RedisStackOverflow.ServiceInterface](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/tree/master/src/RedisStackOverflow/RedisStackOverflow.ServiceInterface) folder at [IRepository.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/src/RedisStackOverflow/RedisStackOverflow.ServiceInterface/IRepository.cs).

Comment: found it, not sure how I glanced over it.